# Lots of Image Caching in GWT

Tags: image, caching, gwt

I'm trying to implement a web-app using gwt. I'm using alot of images (read 1000+, about 200mb), in a low-res . I would like the user to be able to choose to either cache the images forever (if its possible), download them as needed, or the user himself has them in his/her PC and points the app to their location, and it uses them instead. So the question is, is it possible using gwt to save a huge cache indefinetly? Or have the user use it's own images instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your web server to set the expires headers on the images to a date very far in the future, that will tell the browser to effectively cache the images for 'forever'. This is not really something I would try to do in GWT when the browser can do it for you.

Comment: Thing is I would like for the user to have some control over the caching, since it could become huge.
If the user could point to a local directory or image, where the image replacements are, there would be no need for the caching, I would just not cache the images, and ask the user if he would like to download them. Is there a way to load resources from the users local computer?

Comment: You _could_ force browser to download images as files and store them n local storage, but then you would have no way of using them in your web app.

Comment: I suppose you could possibly use JSNI (native JavaScript in your GWT code) or just include some JavaScript and use the file API: http://html5demos.com/file-api

Just my unsolicited two cents, I don't know your reasons for so many images but as a lazy user I would rather have an option to use a version of the site with less images than have to configure a cache location.

Answer (score 0):

It seems simplest to set the cache headers on the images from your server and let the user's browser do the work.  GWT doesn't need to be involved.

If you did want to use GWT and, for example, localStorage, then I think the default maximum on most browsers that support it is 5 MB.